# itextsharp not working

Tags: itext

I am using **iTextSharp** to read pdf file. I am using `pdfreader.GetPageContent()` and  `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage()` methods using simple text extraction strategy.

Both the methods not reading all the pdf's.

For one pdf if I use `GetTextFromPage` it's throwing Index was outside the bounds of the array exception(that page having bullet marks and special chars).

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Recently a few bugs were fixed, so you have two options:

1. Wait for 5.1.4 to be released
2. Download and build [the latest SVN](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/) yourself.

If you still have issues after building the latest SVN, either submit a bug report at sourceforge or subscribe to the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions) and post there.

The recent bug fixes may or may not fix your specific problem. People keep complaining about the parsers, but many are unwilling to submit sample PDF(s) that reproduce the issue.
In other words, if the fixes don't solve your problem and you're unwilling to submit a bug report and sample PDF(s) you're out of luck.

Comment: Just a FYI: please don't submit bug reports at sourceforge, and the mailing list has also been discontinued. iText, like many other open source projects, has moved away from SourceForge. If you think you have found a bug, simply report it here on StackOverflow. Or if you are a customer, report the issue in the iText JIRA.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I've received the bug report in my personal inbox. I've forwarded it to JIRA. Note: kuujinbo has been using iTextSharp for many years and he has contributed by porting (almost) all the iText examples from iText in Action 2nd Edition to C#.